# Why is Android System using Data

Tags: mobile-data, system-apps, data-monitoring, 8.1-oreo

Hi guys I have an android running custom rom on 8.1 . I found this problem when I was downloading files from ANDROID DOWNLOAD MANAGER the speed shown by ADM was very less in comparison to that shown by INTERNET SPEED METER LITE( which I think is good app because of having 10 million downloads) ,to find the culprit who was using data in background I got into SETTINGS

[image: Data usage screenshot]

How can android system use so much data of 691 MB(remember its not play services or any useless google apps since I have only pico version of gapps installed)

[image: On tapping Android system]
[image: Other apps uncluded in this]

I run my net on mobile data where I get 1GB per day , if  i am getting 641 MB robbed How can I stop it without affecting my Android  and is that possible that Cistom rom developers may add some Traffic Bot or Cryptocurrency miner bot to my Android  and name as SYSTEM APPS.

[image: Main data Usage screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For various concerns, some system apps are run within the same process. This makes it hard to distinguish activity from each individual apps (except for storage access). So the "Android System" you see is **the sum of all system apps running in the same process** as the real "System".

Comment: I don't understand Why System Apps need data

Comment: For example, don't you think *WhateverSync* or Push Services need data?

Comment: Push services like that of samsung

Comment: @Pranjal Yep that's one possibllity.

Comment: No download manager is not part of Android System its part of pre installed apps and data usage of both are shown separetly.

Comment: @Pranjal That's a minor mistake. My answer should be overall correct.